# js - shorten multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have an if statement as below.

```
if($("#a").css("display") == "none" && $("#b").css("display") == "none" && $("#c").css("display") == "none" && $("#d").css("display")  == "none" && $("#e").css("display") == "none" && $("#f").css("display") == "none")
```

Is there anyway to shorten this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, something like

```
if ( ! $('#a, #b, #c, #d, #e, #f').is(':visible') ) { .... }
```

returns true if all are hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the ids to be checked in an Array and then use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function, like this

```
var ids = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
if (ids.every(function(id){return $("#" + id).css("display") == "none";})){
   ...
}
```

**Note:** You can decide at runtime, which ids have to be checked, without modifying the condition.

**Note 1:** As [@Jon Dvorak suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422042/js-shorten-multiple-conditions/22422081?noredirect=1#comment34095291_22422081), it was introduced in ES5 only. You can check whether it is compatible with your environment or not with this [compat table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.every)